# Borland C++ ListView Error

Tags: c++, listview, c++builder

I keep getting the error:

> [BCC32 Error] DogReport.cpp(29): E2288 Pointer to structure required on left side of -> or ->*

when trying to compile.

I am trying to populate a `TListView` with elements from my `TList` made up of structs.

```
void __fastcall TDogReportForm::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    DogListView->Items->Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < DogList->Count; i++) {
       TListItem * Item;

       Item = DogListView->Items->Add();
       Item->Caption = DogList->Items[i]->firstName;
       Item->SubItems->Add(DogList->Items[i]->lastName);
       Item->SubItems->Add(DogList->Items[i]->ownerName);
       Item->SubItems->Add(DogList->Items[i]->hours);
       Item->SubItems->Add(DogList->Items[i]->dogNum);
   }
}
```

There is an error on each line that contains `DogList->`

Comment: Well is `Items` an array of pointers? If not that's your problem.

Comment: `DogList` is not declared in your block of code.  Where is it declared and what type is it?

Answer (score 1):

`TList` holds untyped `void*` pointers.  Its `Items[]` property getter returns a `void*` pointer.  You need to type-cast it in order to access your data fields:

```
// DO NOT use the OnCreate event in C++! Use the actual constructor instead...
__fastcall TDogReportForm::TDogReportForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    DogListView->Items->Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < DogList->Count; i++)
    {
       // use whatever your real type name is...
       MyDogInfo *Dog = static_cast<MyDogInfo*>(DogList->Items[i]); // <-- type-cast needed!

       TListItem *Item = DogListView->Items->Add();
       Item->Caption = Dog->firstName;
       Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->lastName);
       Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->ownerName);
       Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->hours);
       Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->dogNum);
   }
}
```

On a side note, instead of copying all of the dog information to the `TListView`, you might consider using the `TListView` in virtual mode (set `OwnerData` to true and assign an `OnData` event handler) so it can display the information directly from `DogList` on-demand when needed:

```
__fastcall TDogReportForm::TDogReportForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    DogListView->Items->Count = DogList->Count;
}

void __fastcall TDogReportForm::DogListViewData(TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item)
{
    // use whatever your real type name is...
    MyDogInfo *Dog = static_cast<MyDogInfo*>(DogList->Items[Item->Index]);

    Item->Caption = Dog->firstName;
    Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->lastName);
    Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->ownerName);
    Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->hours);
    Item->SubItems->Add(Dog->dogNum);
}
```

With that said, you should change `DogList` to use a different container that is more type-safe then `TList`, such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<MyDogInfo> DogList;
...

MyDogInfo &Dog = DogList[index]; // <-- no type-cast needed
Item->Caption = Dog.firstName;
Item->SubItems->Add(Dog.lastName);
Item->SubItems->Add(Dog.ownerName);
Item->SubItems->Add(Dog.hours);
Item->SubItems->Add(Dog.dogNum);
```